# how to handle window in multi thread program

Tags: c#, vsto

Hi i am creating a thread for a process, in that process i am trying to open a window but it open and quickly close. What can i do you that to hold that window and close by manually

```
 private void supportCheckThread(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
    {
        ThreadObject thrdObj = new ThreadObject();
        thrdObj.sender = sender;
        thrdObj.e = e;

        try
        {
            thrCheckStart = new System.Threading.Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(createCheckThread));
            thrCheckStart.Start(thrdObj);              
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { 
        }
        finally { enableBtn(true); }
    }
    private void createCheckThread(object thrdParam)
    {
        ThreadObject ob = (ThreadObject)thrdParam;
        btncheck_Click(ob.sender, ob.e);           
    }
    private void newBtncheck_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
    {
        enableBtn(false);
        supportCheckThread(sender, e);
        string s = "";
    }
```

here how i open that window

```
 h1 = new IDesignSpecWord2007.UI_Forms.HierarchyView(ref Globals.ThisAddIn.Application, ref docm);
                    h1.Show();
```

Comment: The UI belongs to the main thread. Don't try to put the UI into other threads. If your UI does something timeconsuming then put that into a thread but the UI should still be part of the main thread.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the main thread only for UI tasks. A secondary thread is stopped as soon as the code/routine ends. You need to keep a secondary thread running indefinitely if you want to get a form visible all the time. When the thread stops all objects are destroyed and swiped out (so, the form disappears).

Comment: You should displaying any UI windows on the main thread. I just explained the cause why the window is closed so fast.

Comment: please give me some suggestion what should i do. I need to provide a stop button to stop the process that's why i am using threading but i got trouble in some step in threading, give me some suggestion what should i do